# How do I get the SUM of all my counts from the same table?

Tags: php, sql, yii2, yii2-active-records

I'm working with Yii2 and using ActiveRecords. I am trying find ethnic distribution in a department. I have a query that groups the staff into their tribes and further groups them according to gender and returns the total count in each case.

The end result should look similar to this photo:
[image: Photo showing the end result to be achieved]

The ethnic subtotal is given by adding all the totals of all the tribes in the department. So far I have all the totals for all the tribes in each department. How can I add these totals to get the ethnic subtotal?

My code:

```
  $query = StaffEmploymentListView::find()
    ->select([
 
        'DEPT_NAME',
        'TRIBE_NAME', 
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN GENDER='MALE' THEN 1 END) AS MALE_COUNT",        
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN GENDER='FEMALE' THEN 1 END) AS FEMALE_COUNT",
        "COUNT(TRIBE_NAME) AS TRIBE_COUNT",
    ])
    ->groupBy(['DEPT_NAME','TRIBE_NAME']);
```

Raw SQL answers are also welcome.

Comment: Unless you're expecting huge numbers of rows, can't you just write a loop to add the values up?  I know nothing about `yii2`, but another option in many SQL dialects is to use `WITH ROLLUP` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with yii, but generally speaking you can just use `+` to add values, so your selection criteria would be something like `count(...) + count(...)` will select the sum of those two counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.DEPT_NAME,
   SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'MALE' OR GENDER = 'FEMALE' THEN 1 END) as SUM,
   tt.MALE_COUNT,
   tt.FEMALE_COUNT,
   tt.TRIBE_COUNT,
   tt.TRIBE_NAME from 'StaffEmploymentListView' t
     left join (
select DEPT_NAME,
TRIBE_NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'MALE' THEN 1 END) as MALE_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'FEMALE' THEN 1 END) as FEMALE_COUNT,
       count(TRIBE_NAME)                      as TRIBE_COUNT
from 'StaffEmploymentListView' t
group by DEPT_NAME, TRIBE_NAME) tt on t.DEPT_NAME = tt.DEPT_NAME group by t.DEPT_NAME, tt.MALE_COUNT, tt.FEMALE_COUNT, tt.TRIBE_COUNT, tt.TRIBE_NAME;
```

This maybe can help you, i plat with postgresql